# Error "Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have recently installed `Android studio` to create a new app.

But whenever I try to start the emulator to have a preview it gives me the following error:

`Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Option in Emulator Settings=>Scale -->1.Automatic
                                                 2.Hardware-GLES-2.0
                                                 3.Software-GLES-2.0

Here You can choose 3.Software-GLES-2.0 then it will helpful for you.